# Different css style if second child has a certain class

Tags: css

I try to apply a different CSS if the element title has or doesn't have a child with the class find. Is it possible to do it only with CSS ?

Case 1:

```
 <h2 class="title">
    <span class="ico"></span>
    <span class="find">Find</span>
</h2>

.title {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Case 2:

```
 <h2 class="title">
    <span class="ico"></span>
    Find
</h2>

.title {
    padding-left: 9px;
}
```

Comment: No, in your 1st case you should target .find and .title in the second.

Comment: the clue is in the name: cascading

Comment: @GtAntoine Please review an answer I have tried to explain the concept in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent selector, `has()`:

```css
.title:has(.find) {
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.title {
    padding-left: 9px;
}
```

---

<strike>You should following way to apply styling to element or class.
There is a parent class `.title`
Now title have nested 2 class `.ico` is mandatory and `.find` is optional.</strike>

so when you want to apply CSS with the nested element you should use following way `.parent .child` eg. `.title .find`

I have defined default style with `.title`. Whenever `.find` does not exist, it will inherit styles of the parent class.
In our case, I have set default style as `font-size:15px`

In the stylesheet, you seem that I have used `.title .find`, it will apply styles declared in stylesheet where the parent is `.title` and it will apply to all child have `.find` class.
In our case, I have set default style as `font-size:22px`

```css
*{
font-family: "Arial";
}

.title{
  font-size:15px;
}

.title .find{
    font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">
    <span class="ico"></span>
    <span class="find">Find</span>
</h2>

<h2 class="title">
    <span class="ico"></span>
     Find
</h2>
```